# if A is compact and B is closed, there exist $u$ in $A$ and $v$ in $B$ such that $\|u-v\|=\inf\{\|a-b\|\mid a\text{ in }A\text{ and }b\text{ in }B\}$

Tags: analysis

I can't prove this theorem. Could you help me? Thanks for your helps.

$A$ and $B$ are subsets of an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space. Prove that, if $A$ is compact and $B$ is closed, there exist $u$ in $A$ and $v$ in $B$ such that $\|u-v\|=\inf\{\|a-b\| \mid a \in A\text{ and }b \in B\}$.

Comment: I think it's similar. This answer is for 1-dimensional euclidean space (real numbers), but i need an answer to n-dimensional. Anyway, maybe i can generalize this solution to my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You may assume that $B$ is compact by embedding $B$ inside a big enough cube (the intersection of this cube with $B$ is closed and bounded, so it's compact). You have to be a bit careful about how you choose this cube, but I'll let you think about that.

Then, $A\times B$ is compact so the function $(a,b) \mapsto \|a-b\|$ maps onto a compact set (image of compact is compact) and reaches its bounds (compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are closed and bounded).

Comment: Maybe, in your answer, $A$ and $B$ are swapped, for $A$ is originally compact. So I think you wanted to say "you may assume that $B$ is compact" in the first line. Putting that aside,  could you explain the part " the function $(a,b)\mapsto \|a-b\|$ maps onto a compact set and reached its bounds" in a little more detail ? I don't understand what the part means.

Comment: @daㅤedited my answer